# In IOS in app purchase, how to check why response.products.count is always 0?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I was trying to implement Ios in-app purchase for consumable product. I have added 2 products to my app in appstore connect, where ids are like: net.company.app.3000 and net.company.app.10000. Both of them are clear for sale. And in my code, I tried something like:

```
@IBAction func addButtonPushed(_ sender: Any) {
    let ids = Set(["net.company.app.3000","net.company.app.10000"])
    let r = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: ids)
    r.delegate = self
    print("r=\(r)")
    r.start()
}
```

and

```
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {             
     print(response.products.count)
     print(response.invalidProductIdentifiers.description)
    }
```

And here product count is always 0. I have also submitted the product with a version, which got rejected and they rejected it, because the purchase isn't working. And for sure, there is no spelling mistake.

Now, my question is, How can I get the reason/ response of why my product.count is always 0?

Comment: Are you using a sandbox tester to test it?  And also have you tried not using Set and instead just doing: ids = ["net.company.app.3000","net.company.app.10000"] ?

Comment: Yes, I'm a sandbox user and Now just tried not using set, it showed this error: Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'Set<String>. Besides, it used to work, while I uploaded the same code from my company's account. Now, I am trying to upload it from client's account, with changes in bundle id and product ids. But, It is not working now.

Comment: Check the contents of `invalidProductIdentifiers` on your `SKResponse` - it seems likely that your product identifiers aren't correct; have you completed all of the agreements for paid apps in App Store Connect?

Comment: ["net.company.app.10000", "net.company.app.3000"] -> invalidProductIdentifiers content. I checked the spellings many time. They are correct. also, it is not a paid app. the app is free, just there is some consumable items to purchase.

Comment: @TazwarUtshas do you find any solution ? Actually i face the same issue in IAP, I have configured Agreement Tax and Banking, Sandbox Tester, try to login with tester account, In app purchase in target's capabilities is ON, IAP enabled in provision profile, so many times i re-install the app, but still my product count is 0.

Comment: nope @AnandNanavaty bro, it's still showing 0 and I'm still searching for it.

Answer (score 1):

Please checked following points:

```
1) In app purchase in target's capabilities?  
2) IAP should be enable in provision profile. 
3) Also have a look into contract. 
4) Try to delete and install again.
```

Comment: I actually tried these all. Not sure why they are not working.

Comment: Actually my code is ok. I did the code, uploaded app through my companies account at first, that time it worked perfectly. Then I uploaded the same code to my clients account and now it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you force cast Set your SKProduct request like below

```
    let productIDs = Set([
                          "net.company.app.3000",
                          "net.company.app.10000",
                          ])
    //Force Cast
    let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIDs as! Set<String>)
    request.delegate = self
    request.start()
```

If your id's are true and added to AppStore Connect account this should work

Answer (score 0):

I found out, the main problem was with the account owner's payment account settings. So, it is not possible to find error from code in this case.